# Comparing fields in sql server 2008 r2 where there is both letters and numbers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, comparison

I'm fairly new to coding in T-SQL and have run into an issue I have yet to find and answer. I was hoping the experts here and tell me where I have gone wrong.

I am trying to compare 2 columns of serial numbers with a not in statement and it works perfectly if there are only numbers in the columns but if there is a letter in the serial number it just kicks back all the records instead of just the records that are not in the second table. Below is my query I hope someone can point out what I have done wrong. Thank you in advance.

```
@Transaction varchar (50)

AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT       transaction, equiptype, serialnum

FROM             table1

WHERE           ( serialnum NOT IN
        (SELECT serial_num
                      FROM   table2 ) AND transaction = @Transaction)
```

P.S. a is my transaction number I am filtering the record by

### table1-

```
     [transaction] [equiptype] [serialnum]
       12345678        12         56742
       12345678        11         87529
       12345678         8         46259
       87654321         8          the143
       87654321        10          the527
       87654321        11          u3765
```

### table2-

```
       [transdate]    [transaction]   [user]  [equiptype]  [serial_num] [status]
  7/28/11          12345678      test      12       56742     NewStock
        7/28/11        12345678      test         11         87529     NewStock
        7/28/11        87654321      test         11         u3765     NewStock
        7/28/11        87654321      test         10         the527    NewStock
```

Based off this data transaction 12345678 will only return the last record with serialnum 46259 and that works fine but if I try to do the same with transaction 87654321 it will return all records as if the NOT IN statment failed to run instead of serial number the143.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some sample data for tables `table1` and `table2` that will show your issue.

Comment: I will edit my post above to include sample data I hope it will help

Comment: Since you have now added table examples, could you edit the SQL in your question so that it relates to the tables? I see columns a, b, c and d, it would be much easier to understand your question if you replaced those with the proper column names according to your examples.

Comment: my apologize I have corrected the query to reflect the sample data

Comment: What's the data type of [serial_num] in table1 and table2?

Comment: They are Varchar (50) in both tables.

Comment: Do you have spaces before the serial number in one of the tables and not in the other?

Comment: I did check for spaces there are none before the serial number in either table. The fields are populated through a application we have that allows the serial number to be scanned in with a scan gun and the procedure that does the insert if the same for both fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's the from Server Collation. Please try

```
SELECT TRANSACTION, equiptype, serialnum
FROM table1
WHERE  (serialnum  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  
        NOT IN (SELECT serial_num  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS FROM table2 ) 
    AND TRANSACTION = @Transaction)
```

Comment: EricZ,  I changed my query to match the one in your post but now I am getting an error that says                                                                 Msg 248, Level 16, State 1, Procedure InvCompare, Line 5
The conversion of the varchar value '2455768137550020' overflowed an int column.  The only int column in the 2 tables is my index column so I am not sure how this is possible.

Comment: Sounds like your query compare VARCHAR column by convert to INT first. You may check where value '2455768137550020' come from. Then investigate from there

Comment: Value 2455768137550020 is a transaction number I have checked all columns and they are all matching data types on both tables. I have no int columns in either table and @transaction is set as a varchar (50) I am going to keep investigating and hopefully I can find the fault.

Comment: I guess [transaction] column is INT? try compare like this..    AND CAST(transaction AS VARCHAR(50)) = @Transaction

Comment: [Transaction] is a varchar, I tried adding AND CAST(transaction AS VARCHAR (50))=@transaction but I get syntax error- Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure InvCompare, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near '@Transaction'.
did I miss part of your statement?

Comment: If you can reproduce the same error with simplified table/query. And post your test case on your original question will help people know your issue better. The test data you posted was working fine on my sql server 2008

Comment: Thank you EricZ I will try a simplified version and post any error I get from it.

Comment: I found the reason for the error and have resolved it but am still getting all results back instead of just the serial numbers that are not in table2. I will try to simplify the table and query and see if I can duplicate the results I am having now.

Comment: EricZ after retesting the query with the changes you recomended in a seperate test database with just data manually entered the query now works. So I decided to try it with the application and it still does not work so I'm going to run through the code and see if I can find the issue there. Thank you For your help you did resolve my issue with the Query.

Answer (score 0):

I think this query can help you

```
declare @Transaction varchar(50)
set @Transaction='something'

select table1.a,table1.b,table1.c ,table2.d 
from table1 
left join table2 
  on table1.b=table2.d 
where table2.d is null 
  and table1.a=@Transaction
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Tsachi I did try doing a left outer join unfortunately it still kicks back any fields with a letter in them regardless of it being in table2.  I have checked my columns and they are varchar (50) and both Columns are being inputed by the same program so language format should not be a issue. This one really has me stumped.

Comment: I meant a left join my apologize I tried what you showed in your example and still had the same result.

Comment: I do not get a error message it acts like it runs fine but if there is a letter in the serial number it will return all records for that transaction number instead of just what isn't in table2.